# Attribute Error : module tensorflow has no attribute 'get_default_graph'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am getting an error module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph' .Please help me to solve this.
tensorflow  : 2.4.0
VsCode
python 3.6.9

```
enter code here 
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 
n1 =tf.constant(1)
n2 = tf.constant(2)
n3 = n1+n2
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
result1 = sess.run(n3)
print(result1)
print(tf.get_default_graph())
g = tf.Graph()
print(g)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix the formatting of the code, so we can better help you!

Comment: @DapperDuck,thanks for your recommendatation  i have edited my code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform addition OP, you can execute below code using `compat.v1.session` in TF 2.x.

```
import tensorflow as tf

mlt= 2*tf.Variable(4.0)

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
     init= tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
     sess.run(init)
     print(sess.run(mlt))
```

In TF 2.x, eager execution enable by default and working code as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
gt =  2*tf.Variable(4.0)
print(gt)
```